# How do I can change setting RAM in VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

everyone!

I'm a web developer (PHP) and I working on a laptop (MacBook Air middle 2012, 4 GB RAM). For my projects, I must use Ubuntu 14.04. For its, I use VirtualBox with Vagrant.

I always run my tools: Google Chrome, PHPShtorm, Vagrant, VirtualBox, Slack. But I face a problem — insufficient RAM. Most of the RAM takes VirtualBox (2 GB). I can not change the limits, the slider does not work for RAM ([it frozen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjTow.png)).

Please tell me how can I resolve this issue? I have already was thinking, install Linux main system on my MacBook. But this is the extreme case.

Comment: You can only change the RAM if the virtual machine is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your Vagrantfile. There should already be an example line:

```
# vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
```

uncomment it and modify the value to your liking. If there isn't one, enter this block:

```
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
   end
```

below the `Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|` line.